# Key-Value has the data with string value however value string as multiple data which needs to be changed

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, backup, restore

This is the AWS backup restore metadata

I have the below key-value pair data where value has whole string contains multiple data which need to be changed like **false** to **true** or **true** to **false**.

**NetworkInterfaces** key has the string value which has multiple key-value pairs which I am not able to change as it is a whole string.

```
'NetworkInterfaces': '[{
            "AssociatePublicIpAddress":false,
            "DeleteOnTermination":false,
            "Description":"Primary network interface",
            "DeviceIndex":0,
            "Groups":["sg-xyz"],
            "Ipv6AddressCount":0,
            "Ipv6Addresses":[],
            "NetworkInterfaceId":"eni-xyz",
            "PrivateIpAddress":"0.0.0.0",
            "PrivateIpAddresses":[{"Primary":false,"PrivateIpAddress":"0.0.0.0"}],
            "SecondaryPrivateIpAddressCount":0,
            "SubnetId":"subnet-xyz",
            "InterfaceType":"interface"
                    }]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet remains json.loads() to convert it to a dict.
However, the above string isn't a valid json format, the below is ...

```
{"NetworkInterfaces": [{ "AssociatePublicIpAddress":false, "DeleteOnTermination":false, "Description":"Primary network interface", "DeviceIndex":0, "Groups":["sg-xyz"], "Ipv6AddressCount":0, "Ipv6Addresses":[], "NetworkInterfaceId":"eni-xyz", "PrivateIpAddress":"0.0.0.0", "PrivateIpAddresses":[{"Primary":false,"PrivateIpAddress":"0.0.0.0"}], "SecondaryPrivateIpAddressCount":0, "SubnetId":"subnet-xyz", "InterfaceType":"interface" }]}
```

Would suggest to use python re module to convert the string to something similar, which could be later consumed by json module

Adding in a sample code to sanitize the data

```
str = """
'NetworkInterfaces':'[{"AssociatePublicIpAddress":false,"DeleteOnTermination":false,"Description":"Primary network interface","DeviceIndex":0,"Groups":["sg-xyz"],"Ipv6AddressCount":0,"Ipv6Addresses":[],"NetworkInterfaceId":"eni-xyz","PrivateIpAddress":"0.0.0.0","PrivateIpAddresses":[{"Primary":false,"PrivateIpAddress":"0.0.0.0"}],"SecondaryPrivateIpAddressCount":0,"SubnetId":"subnet-xyz","InterfaceType":"interface"}]'
"""


import re
str = re.sub('\'\[', '[', str)
str = re.sub('\]\'', ']', str)
str = re.sub('\'', '\"', str)
str = re.sub('^\n', '', str)
str = re.sub('\n$', '', str)
str = "{" + str + "}"

import json
d = json.loads(str)
print(d["NetworkInterfaces"][0]["AssociatePublicIpAddress"]) # False
```

Comment: How can we convert the string to valid json format using re module as you have mentioned?